# Convert nested JSON to Dataframe with columns referencing nested paths

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, key-value

I am trying to convert a nested JSON into a CSV file with three columns: the level 0 key, the branch, and the lowest level leaf.

For example, in the JSON below:

```
{
    "protein": {
        "meat": {
            "chicken": {},
            "beef": {},
            "pork": {}
        },
        "powder": {
            "^ISOPURE": {},
            "substitute": {}
        }
    },
    "carbs": {
        "_vegetables": {
            "veggies": {
                "lettuce": {},
                "carrots": {},
                "corn": {}
            }
        },
        "bread": {
            "white": {},
            "multigrain": {
                "whole wheat": {}
            },
            "other": {}
        }
    },
    "fat": {
        "healthy": {
            "avocado": {}
        },
        "unhealthy": {}
    }
}
```

I want to create an output like this (didn't include entire tree example just to get point across):

| level 0 | branch | leaf |
| --- | --- | --- |
| protein | protein.meat | chicken |
| protein | protein.meat | beef |

I tried using json normalize but the actual file will not have paths that I can use to identify the nested fields as each dictionary is unique.

This returns the level 0 field but I need to have these as rows, not columns. Any help would be very much appreciated.

I created a function that pcan unnest the json based on key values like this:

```py
import json

with open('path/to/json') as m:
    my_json = json.load(m)


def unnest_json(data):
    for key, value in data.items():
    print(str(key)+'.'+str(value))
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        unnest_json(value)
    elif isinstance(value, list):
        for val in value:
            if isinstance(val, str):
                pass
            elif isinstance(val, list):
                pass
            else:
                unnest_json(val)

unnest_json(my_json)
```

Comment: So then for eg. `lettuce`,  `branch` column will contain something like `carbs._vegetables.veggies`, right?

Comment: @YannisP. exactly

Comment: I can probably just create a function to first flatten and then join everything together and split out first and last words delimited by a ‘.’

Comment: I think this seems to be the option. Pandas might have something too but it is also that your tree paths can have different lengths. DFS looks like an option and it’s similar to what you are saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the cleanest approach but I think you can use some sort of recursive function (`traverse` in below code) to convert the dictionary into a list of column values and then convert them to pandas DataFrame.

```
data = {
    "protein": {
        "meat": {
            "chicken": {},
            "beef": {},
            "pork": {}
        },
        "powder": {
            "^ISOPURE": {},
            "substitute": {}
        }
    },
    "carbs": {
        "_vegetables": {
            "veggies": {
                "lettuce": {},
                "carrots": {},
                "corn": {}
            }
        },
        "bread": {
            "white": {},
            "multigrain": {
                "whole wheat": {}
            },
            "other": {}
        }
    },
    "fat": {
        "healthy": {
            "avocado": {}
        },
        "unhealthy": {}
    }
}

def traverse(col_values, dictionary, rows):
    for key in dictionary:
        new_col_values = list(col_values)
        if dictionary[key]:
            new_col_values[1] += '.' + key
            traverse(new_col_values, dictionary[key], rows)
        else:
            new_col_values[2] = key
            rows.append(new_col_values)

rows = []
for key in data:
    traverse([key, str(key), None], data[key], rows)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["level 0", "branch", "leaf"])
print(df)
```

Comment: Tyvm I appreciate it. This is way more elegant than the solution I was coming up with I updated the post with